# How do I implement a step slider with a logo as indicator head and text on top as the label in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, mobile-development

I have been trying to implement this linear sign up stepper that has a logo as the progress indicator head, some text above it as labels. Please recommend a way to go or flutter package to use.

[image]

I have tried a timeline package but it wasn't dynamic, also tried stepper widget it didn't give the desired output, please help

Answer (score 0):

linear_progress_bar search to pub.dev

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Kindly look at the screenshot of what I intend to implement. it is a sign up custom stepper, it is not just a progress bar, kindly recommend a custom stepper that can achieve that result or advice on how to achieve that